# In Ansible how can I repeatedly fetch a file until a line exists if the system will reboot before that line is updated?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to determine when an update process is completed (the update forces a reboot after some time which is causing trouble).  I suspect the best way to do it is by continuously downloading a file to the localhost from the remote host and checking if a line exists, but I don't see a way to reconnect to that host in a loop with ansible.

Background: I have a node that exists in a private subnet.  when I execute a particular update, the system reboots after an unknown period of time. After it reboots, its possible to determine the update completed because this file (/tmp/softnas-update.status) contains the line-

```
OK. SoftNAS software update to version 4.2.1 completed at Sun Mar  3 05:44:46 EST 2019.
```

The command I use currently, wait_for, is unable to correctly pickup this change over the 17-45 mins it takes because when a reboot occurs during the process the connection will just timeout.

This is an example of what I currently use-

```
  - name: "Wait until Softnas Update completes. This can take 15-45 mins"
    wait_for:
      path: /tmp/softnas-update.status
      search_regex: "^OK. SoftNAS software update to version.*completed at.*$"
      timeout: 3600
    when: update_file.stat.exists and softnas_runupdate
```

is it possible to loop over a an entire playbook that will reconnect to a host each time it checks for the existence of this line?  or is there a better way to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way more difficult than it should be, but I've found a way to do it anyway.

The main issue here is that you can't loop with an until/retries/delay over an include or a block. If you could, this problem could simply be solved by looping over the check and a wait_for_connection.

The way I've found waits for the system to reboot and then starts checking for the line:

```
handlers:
  - name: checkupdatesuccess
    include: checkupdatesuccess.yml
tasks:
   ...
#A task that always get status "changed" to register the handler
  - shell: cat /etc/issue
     notify: checkupdatesuccess
  - name: wait for reboot
    wait_for_connection:
      timeout: 10
    register: result
    until: result is failed
    retries: 300
    delay: 5
```

And the handler tasks:

```
  - wait_for_connection:
      timeout: 100
  - wait_for:
      path: /tmp/softnas-update.status
      search_regex: "^OK. SoftNAS software update to version.*completed at.*$"
      timeout: 3600
    when: update_file.stat.exists and softnas_runupdate
```

You need to use an include in the handler to make sure the tasks are run in the right order. The task "wait for reboot" WILL ALWAYS FAIL, either because of the timeout or, and that is what we are looking for, when the host reboots. When that happens, the handler needs to run, so you need force handlers, either in your config or as parameter --force-handlers on playbook execution. You might have to play around with the timeouts and delays a bit so you don't miss the reboot.